# What is Nepomuk Cleaner? And why does it keep recreating its .desktop file after I delete it?

Tags: applications, menu

When I don't use one of the default applications in elementary OS I usually hide it from the Applications menu using MenuLibre, rather than uninstalling them. However I can't seem to be able to do that with Nepomuk Cleaner, since as soon as I check "hide from menu" another .desktop entry for said program is created, i.e. if I hide "nepomukcleaner.desktop", as soon as I save those changes another file (something like "nepomukcleaner1.desktop") is created, and shows up alongside the previous, now hidden, entry. If I try to hide this one, a third .desktop file is created, and so on.
Same thing happens if I try to delete it.

Comment: What is Nepomuk Cleaner used for and do I need it on my pc, Zorin OS 9,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launching MenuLibre with sudo seems to work, I hid it and it didn't reappear.

Comment: Could you be more detailed?

Comment: Previously, I was just launching MenuLibre from the Applications menu, but every time I tried deleting or hiding the above mentioned .desktop file it would reappear. By launching it from the terminal as superuser, i.e. 'sudo menulibre', I didn't have that issue.

Comment: I meant in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to uninstall it , open **Software Center** search for **Nepomuk Cleaner** and click remove.

This is not included by default in elementary OS so it is safe to remove